# Can i write an object of class in text file in C#

Tags: c#

how can i write an object of a class in a text file not in binary and how can i delete an object from a file. Please help me.

Comment: I want to write an object of class in a text file.

Comment: Do you want to serialize an object to a file?

Comment: Do you mean serialize an object to a file such that you can re-read the file later and obtain an identical instance of the object?

Comment: You can use serialization and write the object to text file. What do you mean by "not in binary" ?

Comment: Confusion is if i am serializing an object then it will be write in binary file not text file.

Comment: yes Sorpigal. please tell me some syntax,

Comment: @user1037750 If you can serialise to XML in a text file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
private void Save<T>(T object, string path)
{
    try
    {
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(object.GetType());
            x.Serialize(writer, settings);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error Saving " + typeof(T).Name + " File " + ex.ToString());
        return;
    }
}
```

This will serialize the object to XML.  You'll just have to make sure that the class and all of it's object tree (all the object's that it contains) are marked as serializable.

Comment: Daryl I am getting an exception using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
 writer has null value. I am giving the path "~\\Files\\login.txt" .

Comment: You could also use the json format. see for instance: http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=344

Comment: @user1037750 You need to give it a full file path (C:\output\test.xml).  Is this in ASP or winform or what?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about serialization

You'll find a lot of resources on the web on that topic
Here's [one](http://sandblogaspnet.blogspot.com/2009/12/serialization-in-net-4.html) for instance